# java: package org.springframework.dao and org.springframework.jdbc.core does not exist

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

Just started dealing with maven and spring. When i'm try to create a DAO and ResultSet and then run the application throws [errors:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBEbY.jpg)

```
Error:(4, 31) java: package org.springframework.dao does not exist
Error:(5, 37) java: package org.springframework.jdbc.core does not exist
Error:(5, 43) java: package org.springframework.context.support does not exist
```

Could you suggest what the problem might be? Not so configured dependencies or something else?

My pom.xml consists of

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The DAO class and Application are attached here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GirQf.png) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGpsh.png)

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? If yes, then use the spring boot plugin, and follow the instructions. If not, remove the spring-boot-starter-jdbc dependency from your dependencies. Regarding your problem, you probably forgot to refresh your project from the pom, because those packages are definitely available from the listed dependencies.

Comment: @JBNizet The project from the pom.xml is updated, the auto-import. Tried to configure as you said, also an error.

Comment: Do some investigation. Can you open the jar files supposed to contain these packages? Can you build with Maven, without using the IDE? What happens if you remove the jar files from your local repository (~/.m2)? What happens if you reimport the project?

Comment: i have the same problem. how did you solve it